# ComboBox DropDown won't stay open after navigating away

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

Basic problem: After a series of actions, my ComboBox won't stay dropped down when I open it. It drops down briefly and then closes immediately.

The ComboBox performs validation in the `Validating` event.
I have an `Exit` Button with `CausesValidation = False`. If I put an invalid entry in the ComboBox and then click on the Exit button, I display a message from the `ExitButton_Click` handler, to allow the user to confirm whether to exit.  If she cancels the exit, and puts focus back on the ComboBox and tries to open it, it won't stay open.

Rather than include all the validation code, I created a much simpler example.  One Form with a ComboBox, `DropDownStyle = DropDown`.  It has a 3 items in it. The Validating event checks for the string "OK" and displays a MessageBox for anything else.

If I click the DropDown arrow when the Form opens, the DropDown opens up and I can select anything. If I enter or select something other than "OK", then click on the "X" on the Form to close it, I get the failure message. Then if I click on the DropDown arrow, it drops down briefly and closes right back up.

Here's the entire code:

```
Public Class Form1
   Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("ABC")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("DEF")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("OK")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles   ComboBox1.Validating
    If ComboBox1.Text <> "OK" Then
        MsgBox("BAD")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

What's going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Me.ActiveControl = nothing` after `e.Cancel = True`. -- I suggest to use the [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) class to handle this. The Validating / Cancel stuff is really annoying.

Comment: That works, thanks!  I found something else that works too - setting the form's AutoValidate property to either EnablePreventFocusChange or EnableAllowFocusChange.

Comment: `EnablePreventFocusChange` is the default and it's part on the original *problem*. `EnableAllowFocusChange` is the opposite: a User is allowed to move the focus and, eventually, to also close the Form. That's why I suggest to use the `ErrorProvider` class to notify of validation errors: no annoying behavior when changing focus and no errors in validation when trying to mitigate the annoying behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check into the ErrorProvider class - haven't used that before.  Setting EnableAllowFocusChange resolves the issue on the little test app above.  But in my real app, setting EnablePreventFocusChange worked, so some other code must be interacting with it. There are a lot of dependencies from one control to the next - enabling and disabling them based on what's in the last control.  Thanks for the input!